# Trying to use keys while program is minimized

Tags: delphi

I'm trying to make it so that when I press Left, Right, Up, or Down on the keyboard, it moves my cursor to the edges of my screen.

The problem is that, when I minimize the program, the keys don't work.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: What have you already tried and what are you trying to archive?
Please include some source code to show your problem.

Comment: Have you ever experienced another program which reacts to key presses although its windows are minimized? If no: could it have a reason? As in: that's the point of being minimized?

Comment: Users are going to be very upset with you when they try to move the text cursor in Word or navigate an Excel spreadsheet using the arrow keys. I'd delete your app so fast  that you'd feel the breeze in your hair wherever you are located.

Answer (score 3):

When your window is minimized, it does not have input focus, and thus cannot receive normal window messages regarding input events.

So, to do what you are asking, you will need to hook the keyboard instead, either with [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw) or [`RegisterRawInputDevices()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerrawinputdevices).